# NextJS on GAE - Error: EROFS: read-only file system

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I'm trying to deploy a Next application with custom server.js into GAE. I can run the project with no problems on local and even on the google GCP CLI. The problem right now is after the app is deployed to GAE successfully via `gcloud app deploy`, I'm getting the following error when opening the app.

```
2020-03-30 21:41:21.748 HKT
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, unlink '/srv/dist/functions/next/BUILD_ID'
Expand all | Collapse all{
 insertId: "5e81f701000b6ba4e770be02"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/next-gae/logs/stderr"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-03-30T13:41:21.749839891Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 textPayload: "Error: EROFS: read-only file system, unlink '/srv/dist/functions/next/BUILD_ID'"  
 timestamp: "2020-03-30T13:41:21.748452Z"  
}
```

My app.yaml is below:

```
runtime: nodejs10
```

.gcloudignore

```
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud Platform
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below:
.git
.gitignore

# Node.js dependencies:
node_modules/
*.hot-update.js*

# Other config and Files
README.md
.eslintignore
.eslintrc
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "next-gae",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.7",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.15.0",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.15.0",
    "@sentry/node": "^5.15.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.2.6",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.2.6",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.2.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.2.6",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "^5.2.6",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^5.2.6",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.2.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.2.6",
    "antd": "^3.26.7",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.5.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.9.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.8.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "helmet": "^3.21.2",
    "hpp": "^0.2.3",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^7.1.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^7.1.0",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "next": "^9.1.7",
    "next-antd-aza-less": "^1.0.2",
    "next-optimized-images": "^2.5.5",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^4.0.1",
    "nocache": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-smooth-scrollbar": "^8.0.6",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.0.1",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.21.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-multi": "^0.1.12",
    "redux-observable": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.5.1",
    "storybook-addon-figma": "^0.1.0",
    "storybook-readme": "^5.0.8",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.1",
    "yup": "^0.28.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "flow": "flow",
    "eslint": "eslint \"./**/*.{jsx,js}\"",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint --fix",
    "lint:dry": "npm run lint --fix-dry-run",
    "build-next": "next build \"src/app/\"",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "predeploy": "npm run build-all",
    "start": "cd \"src/app/\" ; NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "deploy:gae": "npm run pre-start; npm run build-next; gcloud app deploy",
    "fmt": "prettier --config .prettierrc.yml --write \"{!(node_modules),!(__mock__)/**/}*.{jsx,js,json,md,ts}\""
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{jsx,js}": [
      "flow focus-check",
      "npm run lint:fix",
      "git add"
    ],
    "*.{jsx,js,json,md,ts}": [
      "npm run fmt",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.22.0",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.15.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.111.3",
    "husky": "^3.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "lint-staged": "^9.4.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting is telling you that the path you are trying to delete from is read only. [In GAE standard the paths you can write to are limited](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features):

> Java 8, Java 11, Node.js, Python 3.7, PHP 7.2, PHP 7.3, Ruby 2.5
>   (beta), Go 1.11, Go 1.12, and Go 1.13 have read and write access to
>   the /tmp directory.

You should handle your files in the /tmp directory or use App Engine Flex if you cannot do so.

Comment: Im getting similar error in google cloud function even if the file has been store in /tmp folder
`Error: EROFS: read-only file system, unlink '/workspace/tmp/94c8aa2452bccd82ee129b46f7c4be79'`