# NestJS Project on Google App Engine shows error "Could not write file" && " EROFS: read-only file system"

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-app-engine, nestjs

I am struggling to solve error as like below when i deploy NestJS project on Google App engine.

> error TS5033: Could not write file '/workspace/dist/properties/dto/property.filter.dto.d.ts': EROFS: read-only file system, open '/workspace/dist/properties/dto/property.filter.dto.d.ts'.

### `app.yaml` file is below

```
runtime: nodejs10
env: standard

default_expiration: "4d 5h"

## to specify database
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "your instance connection name"

env_variables:
  DATABASE_HOST: "/cloudsql/your instance connection name"
  DATABASE_USERNAME: "user name"
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: "password"
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: "your instance connection name"

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

### `tsconfig.json` file is below

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

it seems i can not write files in dist folder on App Engine but i am not sure why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

As this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features) indicates:

> Java 8, Java 11, Node.js, Python 3, PHP 7, Ruby, Go 1.11, and Go 1.12+
> have read and write access to the /tmp directory.

So, this means that only in the `/tmp` directory you will be able to perform writting operations and any others you won't as they arey read-only, which will include the `workspace` and consequently the `dist`. As clarified in this answer from a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60950921/12767257), you will need to handle your files in either the `/tmp` directory or start to use App Engine Flex, where you can write in other directories.

Comment: Thank you for your comment gso_gabriel. but i could not understand what you mean because i just deployed nestJS project and in my local there are no workspace directory.. if you could please tell me how to handle my  files in either the /tmp directory" thanks

Comment: hello this problem solved by just updated package.json. i just modified start script to `node dist/main.js` then application run successfully thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a TypeScript error. TS5033 (TS - TypeScript). I had a similar problem deploying my Node.js app on Google App Engine and after 24 hours of searching and trying many ways to solve the problem, I finally stumbled upon and tried this:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/running-custom-build-step

You will see in that article a proper package.json for deploying TypeScript based Nonde.js app on Google App Engine. The Key was merely the addition of the following script on package.json:

"gcp-build": "tsc -p ."

Some folks would ask that you move the typescript from devDependencies to Dependencies. But if you read that article and I can attest to it - that all of that is not necessary. Once you tell Google App Engine how to build Typescript by adding the above script, then your start script can just be:

"start": "node ./dist/index.js"

And you are good to go...

I hope this will help someone that faces a similar problem!