# NestJS Project on Google App Engine shows error “Could not write file”

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-app-engine, nestjs, google-cloud-build

I try to deploy my nestJS application in app engine with standard env instance. But I received this error:

```
0mCould not write file '/workspace/dist/my/ts/file': EROFS: read-only file system, open '/workspace/dist/my/ts/file'.
```

I understand that nodejs will only be able to perform writing in the /tmp directory.

**My question is**: how can I put the workspace folder (created by cloud build) into tmp folder

here is my **app.yaml**:

```
runtime: nodejs12
env: standard
```

here my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "elengui-api",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "npx @nestjs/cli build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "npx @nestjs/cli start",
    "start:dev": "npx @nestjs/cli start --watch",
    "start:debug": "npx @nestjs/cli start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "gcp-build": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.6.3",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.2.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^0.3.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^7.1.5",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^0.4.3",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^4.7.13",
    "@nestjs/throttler": "^1.1.3",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.5",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/hapi__joi": "^17.1.6",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.33",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "crypto-random-string": "^3.3.1",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hbs": "^4.1.1",
    "helmet": "^4.4.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "nodemailer": "^6.5.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.31"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.5.4",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.1.3",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.5.1",
    "@types/cron": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.6",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.1",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.3",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.8",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is explained with trying to write to directory diffent than `/tmp`.

[Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-temp-files) contain following:

> While Cloud Storage is the recommended solution for reading and
> writing files in App Engine, if your app only needs to write temporary
> files, you can use standard Node.js methods to write files to a
> directory named /tmp.

So this is the error, it seems your code is trying to use directory mentioned in the error massage. I do not have playgroud at hand for it, but I suppose this is related with `start` script using `npx`. You should use `node <your-app.js>` instead. I found different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020046/nestjs-project-on-google-app-engine-shows-error-could-not-write-file-erof) where this was confirmed by question poster.